# Mercurial: How to change namespace, but still be able to pull changes from fork

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, mercurial, pull

I have the following problem. I am developing in C# MVC3.

I have a solution, lets call it Solution A, in which I have developed a base set of features and functionality. I am then forking this and changing the namespace of the projects in the solution to something more suitable to the specific site. TheHotSauce is not a good production name:) I now want to pull updates to Solution A into this new solution, but is seems that changing the namespace and hence the folder structure has caused issues here.

Please would someone suggest or explain a good approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to update the default pull path. See [`hg help paths`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#paths). It explains that you an just edit the `.hg\hgrc` file. It contains something like this now:

```
[paths]
default = C:\path\to\your\old\solution
```

and you simply update the path to the new name of your solution. That will make `hg pull` and `hg push` use that location by default.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a go with this.